# How to save each json value into localStorage in ionic

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the follows json from my rest api:

```
{"data":[{
"loginStatus":"Valid",
"CustomerName":"Fagbemi Ayodele","Mobile":null,
"Email":"fagbemiayodele48@gmail.com",
"CustomerID":"3"
}]}
```

In my **login.ts** I am trying to save each value from the json into localStorage by doing the following:

```
this.authService.login(this.loginData).then((result) => {

        this.data = result;


          localStorage.setItem('loginStatus', this.data.loginStatus);
          localStorage.setItem('CustomerName', this.data.CustomerName);
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyApp);
          this.loading.dismiss();

}
```

When I tried to printout the value in console i.e `console.log(this.data.loginStatus);` it returns `undefined`.

How can I get each value?

Answer (score 0):

this is the method i use for my storage i hope it can be at help for yo u 2.

set value

```
public set(keyValue,value){
    return this.storage.set(keyValue,value);
  }
```

get value

```
 public async get(keyValue){
    return await this.storage.get(keyValue);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The **data** property of the JSON returned is not an object but an array. So your code should be like this

```
this.authService.login(this.loginData).then((result) => {

    this.data = result[0];

    localStorage.setItem('loginStatus', this.data.loginStatus);
    localStorage.setItem('CustomerName', this.data.CustomerName);
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyApp);
    this.loading.dismiss();
}
```

Notice how I got the 0 index of the result array.